# How can I change default settings for HP Laserjet Pro 100 Color MFP 175?

Tags: printing

I've already created a new Preset configuration, but I cannot set it as the new default settings.

Anyone has any clues on achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you set the default settings from the browser going to the address http://localhost:631?

For example, I go to `http://localhost:631/printers/Canon_MX310_series` and from there clicking on administration I can choose: `Set Default Options`. Those set there usually get respected.